# difference between inherited and own variables of classes

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

Can someone explain me the difference between own variable of the class and inherited variable?
For example in this code:

```
class First
{
public:
    int test;

    First::First()
    {
        test = 5;
    }
};

class Second : public First
{
public:
    void setTest(int test)
    {
        Second::test = test;
    }
    int Second::GetTestFirst()
    {
        return First::test;
    }
    int Second::GetTestSecond()
    {
        return Second::test;
    }
};
int main()
{
    int input;
    Second * sec = new Second;
    cin >> input;
    sec->setTest(input);   //for example 15
    std::cout << sec->GetTestFirst();
    std::cout << sec->GetTestSecond();
    return 0;
}
```

What is the difference between output of GetTestFirst() and GetTestSecond()? Is it pointing to same memory block? And if it is the same thing, which one is better to use?

Comment: Qualifying member definitions within the class is invalid and pointless. Don't.

Comment: The qualifiers are only necessary if your derived class has a member of the same name, so you can differentiate between them. But that should be avoided.

Comment: There is only one member variable in either class. `test`, `First::test` and `Second::test` all refer to the same thing within `Second`. It is better to use just `test`.

Comment: You have declared only one member variable int test; in you First class and so, both the function calls are making a reference to the same memory location 5. However if you define another variable int test; in your Second class then they will be making different reference accordingly. Also, you have to be aware that the Second class is also First class. So you can do something like: Second *sec = new First(); now all attributes that belongs to the First class will be in the Second class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference - a `Second` object has only one `test` member, inherited from `First`. So saying

```
return First::test;
```

is redundant - you can just use

```
return test
```

(without `this` as the other answer states - this is not necessary as well). Also you should not use

```
Second::GetTestFirst()
```

and similar. The compiler knows perfectly that it is compiling `Second`.

```
GetTestFirst()
```

is enough. As far as I can see all `First::` and `Second::` in your code are not necessary. And the last observation: in C++ you should not use dynamic memory unless you need to. Instead of

```
Second * sec = new Second;
```

you should use

```
Second sec;
```

and `.` instead of `->` later.

Comment: Ok any what if I want to make "void SetTest(int x)" in child class? Is better to use "First::test = x" or "Second::x = x"? or it does not matter?

Comment: It will be weird to have setter in child and member in parent, but it is valid. And again - unless you need to distinguish different members you should not use `First::` or `Second::`. In your example there is only one member `test` so don't use those prefixes, because it is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

GetTestFirst() and GetTestSecond() does the same thing since *test* variable only defined inside the base class. Proper way to address that variable would be using *this* keyword;

```
return this->test;
```

Comment: That isn't the "proper" way. There's no need to use `this`, since member variables (including those inherited from a base class) are in scope inside member functions. It's just unnecessary typing.

Comment: Using `this->` is considered to be a good practise, and it helps A LOT to people reading the code for the first time.

Comment: I agree, *proper* was an incorrect word to use. Also, yes, you don't have to use *this* keyword. However, I believe *this* is a stronger statement while performing code reviews.

Comment: @Kupto good practice according to whom? Please cite a reputable source.